# Create and download Word file in Blazor

Tags: ms-word, download, blazor, openxml

I am trying to create a Word file and download the created file in clients browser.

The creation part seems to work fine and I can open the file manually from its Folder.
But the downloaded file in browser does not open correctly and produces an error
"The file is corrupt and cannot be opened"

I am using the code from here
[Microsoft instructions for downloading a file in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

My code seems like this

```
 private async Task CreateAndDownloadWordFile()
{
    var destination = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var fileName = destination + "\\test12.docx";
    //SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create
(fileName, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        // Add a main document part.
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

        // Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

        // String msg contains the text, "Hello, Word!"
        run.AppendChild(new Text("New text in document"));

    }
    var fileStream = GetFileStream();
    using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);

}



private Stream GetFileStream()
{
    var randomBinaryData = new byte[50 * 1024];
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(randomBinaryData);

    return fileStream;
}
```

And I use this Javascript code

```
async function downloadFileFromStream(fileName, contentStreamReference) {
const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

triggerFileDownload(fileName, url);

URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

function triggerFileDownload(fileName, url) {
const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
anchorElement.href = url;
anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
anchorElement.click();
anchorElement.remove();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the downloaded file in browser does not open correctly

That is probably because you

1. First create a Word document
2. And then download `var randomBinaryData = new byte[50 * 1024];`

> the downloaded file in browser

Check those. Are they exactly `50 * 1024` bytes ?

--

Also, you shouldn't pass the full `C:\...` path to the download funtion.

```cs
  var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
  using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
//await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
  await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", "suggestedName", streamRef);
```

Comment: can you please give some more explanation about that?
I think I first create the word document in "using{}"  and then download it.
Where exactly is the wrong order?

Comment: What is `GetFileStream()` and why do you still have it?  Delete it and see how far you get.

Comment: I use the fileStream here 
using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
If I delete GetFileStream() I will not have fileStream to pass it to DotNetStreamReference

Comment: Correct.  You need a different stream. Try it with one that holds a Word document.